# Enable https using UVICORN

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I tried this tutorial (https://dev.to/rajshirolkar/fastapi-over-https-for-development-on-windows-2p7d) and then when I went to my browser but I cannot access my localhost address using https, if I try http it works but I need to use HTTPS.

Here is the code I tried:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app.api:app",
                 host="localhost",
                 port=8432, 
                 reload=True,
                 ssl_keyfile="./key.pem", 
                 ssl_certfile="./cert.pem")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this

```
if __name__ = 'main':
    uvicorn.run(
               app,
               host="0.0.0.0",
               port=8432,
               ssl_keyfile="./localhost+4-key.pem",
               ssl_certfile="./localhost+4.pem"
               )
```

If you pass directly your `app` instead the description of attributes `app.api:app` you can't use the automatic reload and the workers, but it is an easy way to test if the things are good configured.

Recommendations:

Ensure you are running this command: `mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1` in the folder of your project, also you are probably writing wrong the name of the ssl certificates.

Comment: Do we need .pem files for running https? How to create ssl certificate for https?

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error: "Unsupported upgrade request". Try install uvicorn[standard].

Comment: AFTER verification the issue is about, Unverified HTTPS request. I can conclude that the certification is not supported by Firefox.  It tried Chrome browser and it works perfectlty. From the client application, I should just accepted the provided certification